# Windows 10 crashes after about 3 minutes with Ubuntu 14.04 installed

Tags: boot, multi-boot, windows-10, grub2

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my machine on a partition. I wanted to install Windows 10, so I installed it to another partition using a USB. Later there was the issue where I could not select the OS as it was always going to Windows 10. So I installed the boot-repair on a live Ubuntu and did the repairs. Now during boot it shows both OSs as expected.

But when I login to Windows 10, and after using for about 3-5 minutes, the machine crashes and restarts.

Any idea on how to find the issue?

Comment: Would be nice if crash reason, "blue screen" error code is posted - this would narrow the problem.

Comment: @snayob , there is no blue screen. It just powers off. Ubuntu OS is working fine without an issue.

Comment: You could look in Event Viewer for crash reason. Check all "red" events in "Administrative events".

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same, but only since today. Yesterday and the days before - no problem at all. Very strange...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Clonezilla or some other disk imaging live-cd, and make a full disk backup, if you have important files on your Ubuntu system you don't want to lose.
2. Use Gparted live or something like that to wipe out the partition table (removing all the partitions)
3. Now, install Windows 10 *first*, using the iso file on microsoft's website on a partition with the size you want (you can't take the whole disk, you need space for ubuntu), and then, after rebooting and configuring stuff, update the whole system, reboot again.
4. Now see if the system is stable, surf the web and maybe run a benchmark. If it's stable, then install ubuntu.
5. Install Ubuntu 14.04 from a live-cd based on the latest iso.
6. Now, select that you want your ubuntu OS to be alongside windows 10.

Ubuntu should now setup a grub multiboot, and hopefully your Win10 will remain stable. If it wasn't stable without ubuntu, the try install drivers from your motherboard-company, or just wait until Microsoft get's Windows 10 bug-free for your system.

Good luck!